# Defining a two variables function by Hessian Matrix

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, function-construction

I need to define a function `h` by the Hessian matrix:

```
f[x_, y_] := x^3 + y^2
h[x_, y_] := D[f[x, y], {{x, y}, 2}]
```

and evaluating it on a point, e.g. `(0,0)`. But I obtained the following error:

```
General: 0 is not a valid variable.
```

Someone knows what should I do?

Comment: This is one of the rare occasions where I would suggest to use `Set` instead of `SetDelayed`. Try `h[x_, y_] = D[f[x, y], {{x, y}, 2}]`. It should work provided that both `x` and `y` have no values assigned to them.

Comment: Variant of @HenrikSchumacher suggestion is` h[x_, y_] := Evaluate @ D[f[x, y], {{x, y}, 2}]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
f[x_, y_] := x^3 + y^2

h[x1_, y1_] := D[f[x, y], {{x, y}, 2}] /. {x -> x1, y -> y1}

h[0, 0]
```

> {{0, 0}, {0, 2}}

Comment: Using `h[x1_, y1_] = 
 Block[{x, y}, D[f[x, y], {{x, y}, 2}] /. {x -> x1, y -> y1}]` provides robustness towards potential values for `x` and `y` as well as performance (since the symbolical computation for the derivatives has to be performed only once).

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thx I got it now